# "Recent documents" API in .NET?

Tags: .net

For my document-based application I want to have a list of "Recent Documents", as many others do.  I'm happy to implement this myself manually by writing to a settings file or whatever, but was wondering if there's a component in the .NET framework that will do this for me.

Seems like a common function that many developers would need, and I don't want to write code that .NET provides.  I'm using .NET 3.5 with WPF for the UI.

Comment: perhaps wrap a Framework queue to limit the number of items in it.

Comment: Right, it wouldn't be too hard to do, I was just wondering if there's some easy, built-in way to register and retrieve those files, similar to the way .NET provides facilities to manage user and application settings, resources, localization, etc.  The more code I write myself, the more I have to test and maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the .NET framework doesn't contain such a feature.

However, rather than implementing it yourself from scratch, you might want to use the dedicated Windows API :

- [AddMRUStringW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776384%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [CreateMRUListW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776394%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [EnumMRUListW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776412%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [FreeMRUList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776425%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers [ha, no pun intended], although the Win32 APIs are pretty much the last thing I want to deal with.