# how to get a list of recent documents in windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7

in my app i want to get all paths of recent used document in windows 7 (for all types of documents) , i am using c# ,so is there any method to do that ? help me please? .

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196511/recent-documents-api-in-net

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent);
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path);
```

Answer (score 3):

This kind of data is stored in the registry. A Google search led me to the following:

> Description: Recently opened files from Windows Explorer
>   Location: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
>
> Description: Recently Opened Office Docs
>   Location: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\Recent

(from: http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/windows-forensics-registry-and-file-system-spots)

Comment: You don't want to count on those. They could change in future versions. Always use the special folder enums (or the C++ equivalent if you're in native code) so you are future proof.