# Last accessed files on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows

How can I retrieve a list of most recent opened/accessed files, not just from **Open File dialog** or **MRU list**, via C# without having to scan the entire hard drive?

Thanks

[Getting the last opened file in fileopen dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714310/getting-the-last-opened-file-in-fileopen-dialog-box)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3636/Add-Most-Recently-Used-Files-MRU-List-to-Windows-A

Comment: Are you after all files in the system, or just files opened within your application?

Comment: Thanks, http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/windows-forensics-registry-and-file-system-spots#Recently%20opened%20files%20from%20Windows%20Explorer contains a lot of information. However, I was testing with for example Open File from Notepad++, the registry keys there didn't capture the information. I tried drag file from Explorer to Notepad++, also tried open it from Notepad++ Open File Dialog, also tried save it. But, no joy. Any reliable mechanism out there?

Answer (score 2):

(Posting the link to the answer as a public courtesy to get this off the unanswered list, as I don't have close privileges yet.)

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent);
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path);
```

CREDIT TO [AS-CII](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464250/as-cii)

[ORIGINAL ANSWER HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569862/how-to-get-a-list-of-recent-documents-in-windows-7)

Comment: Thanks but no joy - see above comment where I tested open/save file with Notepad++ for instance. SpecialFolder.Recent did not capture it. Neither was the information found in registry keys found under http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/windows-forensics-registry-and-file-system-spots#Recently%20opened%20files%20from%20Windows%20Explorer

Comment: Dont think you're right, I just tested with Notepad++. "Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent" is able to capture if I open a file from Notepad++ via standard "Open File Dialog". If I DRAG DROP a file from Explorer to Notepad++, this won't capture it. Further, "Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent" is same as "C:\Users\$USERNAME$.$WORKSTATIONNAME$\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"

Comment: Of course, again, I reposted this from another question in which the answer works, so I can't really take credit for it either way. However, as I know enough about C# to make me dangerous, and quite a lot about Windows in general, I would recommend checking into whether you have something that is wiping your Recent Documents on your computer, Swab.Jat. I know CCleaner removes those as part of the cleaning process (optionally), as do a lot of cleaning software titles. Just a random idea, it may not be that at all.