# Checking the last accessed files on Windows 10 in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, windows-10

I'm writing a small tool to help my workflow as an artist, and it'd be neat if it could check a list of recently accessed files on my computer for a `*.psd` (photoshop) file.  The last file of this type is always the one I'd like to read, so it works out well.

Does Windows 10 allow me to see a list of paths to my computer's most recently accessed files, which I might leverage through C++?

(I'd never ask for this kind of feature as a dev, it seems like a huge privacy issue when the dev and user are not the same person... But if it's there I may as well use it.)

Comment: *Does Windows 10 allow me to see a list of paths to my computer's most recently accessed files,* -- Do you know of any application or existing utility that does this?  That's one way you can get a good idea of whether it is possible or not.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Now that you mention it, I guess I don't know of any that does even though it'd be advantageous in their use-case, so perhaps not.

Comment: You can `FindFirstFile` and friends to walk a volume. The access time might not be usable. Modified time is.

Comment: @anders - Thanks, I'm trying something like this, though narrowing the space way down by specifying a directory first, and using `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` and `std::filesystem::last_write_time` to brute force it

Comment: If you are willing to consider C#, you could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569862/how-to-get-a-list-of-recent-documents-in-windows-7).